# BelongsTo in Sails.js

Tags: sails.js, associations

**Hello, I need your help please with 2 questions.**

I have 2 Models
One to Many

```
(One) Customer{ id, names, dni} -> Invoice {id, date, ....customer_id} (Many)
```

**1. How can I get this?**
I need to consume the api "GET /api/invoices" and that the json return of this, in turn, returns an array

```
[{
 id: 1,
date: '2022-01-01',
  ....invoice
   customer: {
       dni: 1,
      names: 'Example'
  }
},
{
 id: 2,
date: '2022-01-02',
  ....invoice
   customer: {
       dni: 2,
      names: 'Example 2'
  }
},

]
```

So far what I have found in the sailsjs documentation are only examples with POPULATE, where they only show how to list the User model with its corresponding created ones (hasMany)

```
//var users = await User.find().populate('pets');
  // The users object would look something like the following
  // [{
  // id: 123,
  // firstName: 'Foo',
  // lastName: 'Bar',
  // pets: [{
      // id: 1,
      // breed: 'labrador',
      // type: 'dog',
      // name: 'fido',
      // user: 123
  // }]
  // }]
//---This is not what I need.
```

Is there a function or configuration that I have not found?
Or would I do something like this?

```
Invoices.find().exec(async(err, invoices)=>{
            if(invoices){
                for(i = 0; i< invoices.length; i++){
                     const customer = await Customer.find({id: invoices[i].customer_id});
                    invoices[i].customer = customer;
            }
});
```

The point is that this takes much longer than doing a query with join

```
   const invoices = await sails.sendNativeQuery('SELECT * from INVOICE A A inner join CUSTOMER B on A.customer_id=B.id ', []);
```

But I don't know how to get a JSON with the previous structure if I do it by query

**2. What is the best option that can solve my problem?**

Answer (score 0):

The `populate` method works in both directions: `oneToMany`, `manyToMany`, and `manyToOne`:

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries/populate

If any condition is required, you could check the details on the section `Populating a collection association`:

```js
var usersNamedFinn = await User.find({ name:'Finn' })
.populate('currentSwords', {
  where: {
    color: 'purple'
  },
  limit: 3,
  sort: 'hipness DESC'
});
```